# Splitting a text in Unix

Tags: bash, unix, cut

I am writing a simple script that splits a variable that holds some text by using below code:

```
#!/bin/sh

SAMPLE_TEXT=hello.world.testing

echo $SAMPLE_TEXT
OUT_VALUE=$SAMPLE_TEXT | cut -d'.' -f1

echo output is $OUT_VALUE
```

I am expecting output as `output is hello` but when I run this program then I am getting output as `output is`. Please let me know where I am doing mistake?

Comment: `OUT_VALUE=$(echo "$SAMPLE_TEXT" | cut -d'.' -f1)` or better, `OUT_VALUE=$(cut -d'.' -f1 <<< "$SAMPLE_TEXT")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To evaluate a command and store it into a variable, use `var=$(command)`.

All together, your code works like this:

```
SAMPLE_TEXT="hello.world.testing"

echo "$SAMPLE_TEXT"
OUT_VALUE=$(echo "$SAMPLE_TEXT" | cut -d'.' -f1)
# OUT_VALUE=$(cut -d'.' -f1 <<< "$SAMPLE_TEXT") <--- alternatively

echo "output is $OUT_VALUE"
```

Also, note I am adding quotes all around. It is a good practice that will help you in general.

---

Other approaches:

```
$ sed -r 's/([^\.]*).*/\1/g' <<< "$SAMPLE_TEXT"
hello

$ awk -F. '{print $1}' <<< "$SAMPLE_TEXT"
hello

$ echo "${SAMPLE_TEXT%%.*}"
hello
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer by fedorqui is the correct answer. Just adding another approach...

```
$ SAMPLE_TEXT=hello.world.testing
$ IFS=. read OUT_VALUE _ <<< "$SAMPLE_TEXT"
$ echo output is $OUT_VALUE 
output is hello
```

Comment: This answer is not the best approach, but quite useful to split the string into an array, using `read -a`.

Comment: I would argue this is superior, as it does not require extra processes to handle something `bash` can do itself.

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand on @anishane's comment to his own answer:

```
$ SAMPLE_TEXT="hello world.this is.a test string"
$ IFS=. read -ra words <<< "$SAMPLE_TEXT" 

$ printf "%s\n" "${words[@]}"
hello world
this is
a test string

$ for idx in "${!words[@]}"; do printf "%d\t%s\n" $idx "${words[idx]}"; done
0   hello world
1   this is
2   a test string
```